# Qt/C++: Checkable button and infinite loop

Tags: c++, qt

I'm coding a Qt Gui and I'm trying to implement a new feature, I now the precise result I want to arrive at but not how to code it.
I'm trying to add a checkable button that when checked would run a function that would only stop when the button is unchecked, but every second a PaintArea I have on the window would be updated (letting me see how the multiple executions of my function are changing my data). It seem that I'll need to use some QThread objects, but just the part dealing with the button is already counter intuitive to me, I've been trying to play with the autoRepeatDelay and autoRepeatInterval without getting my hand on what they do and how they could be useful to me.

I guess that what I'm trying to code is not really original, would have an idea of the steps to implement it, or an example of a code?

Edit:
According to the first answers (thank you for them by the way) my question may not be clear. Putting on the side the thread thing, I'd like to implement an infinite loop that only starts when a pressbutton goes to pressed position (it's a checkable button) and stops only when leaving it. The first version I tried to do (with a while(button->isChecked() loop) would completely freeze as the application would be running the loop, the gui would freeze and the button couldn't be turned off (hence the idea of running it in a separate thread). Voila! I hope it's a clearer formulation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need some function to be executed in infitine loop until checkbox is checked? If yes - please, update your question to be simple to understand.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Just took note of your comment and updated the question, thank you.

Comment: Other way is to create a timer and call you function on each timer event. Because any infinite loop, even in other thread, may cause a lot of "lags".

Comment: Indeed, it's really odd, I managed to run the loop in another thread, but it still totally freezes the gui, I even gave up on the checkable button for a button that would just start/stop at clicking, but once started the whole thing freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple skeleton of something that might work. Without knowing your exact requirements, it may or may not be right for your problem. Hopefully it will give you a few hints that do actually help.

```
void Ui::buttonPressedSlot(bool checked){
    if (checked){
        Processor *processor = new Processor;
        connect(this, SIGNAL(abortCalculations()), processor, SLOT(abort()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(processor, SIGNAL(updateNeeded()), this, SLOT(updateGui()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(processor);
    } else {
        emit abortCalculations(); // this is a signal in your UI class
    }
}
```

You can then use the following for your calculations.

```
class Processor : public QObject, public QRunnable{ // QObject must always be first in multiple inheritance
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ~Processor();

    void run();

public slots:
    void abort();
    void doCalculations();

signals:
    void updateNeeded(); // connect this to the GUI to tell it to refresh

private:
    QScopedPointer<QEventLoop> loop;
};

Processor::~Processor(){
    abort();
}

void Processor::run() {

    loop.reset(new QEventLoop);

    QTimer timer;
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doCalculations()));
    timer.setInterval(1000);
    timer.start();

    loop->exec();
 }

 void Processor::abort(){
    if (!loop.isNull()){
        loop->quit();
    }
 }

 void Processor::doCalculations(){
     // do whatever needs to be done

     emit updateNeeded();
 }
```

Comment: First many many thanks for the suggestion (I'll try implementing that soonish, I've got something else in my hands in this very moment) but, it seems to me that your code updates the PaintArea at every execution of the loop, when I'd like it to be done only at the end of the timer, so I guess that I'll have to move the `emit updateNeeded()` to the end of the run() declaration. Also, I'd really need my program to not abort in the middle of one of the loop's executions but wait for it to be done and stop there. I'm not familiar with this QEventLoop, but do they natively support that? Thank you!

Comment: `QEventLoop` is the underlying controller of the event message dispatching in Qt. If you've used `QCoreApplication::exec()` or `QDialog::exec()`, then you've used `QEventLoop` without knowing it.

Comment: If you move `emit updateNeeded()` to the end of the `run()` function, the signal will only be emitted once you abort. At the moment, it will be emitted at the end of the `doCalculations()` function, which itself gets called once a second, when the `QTimer::timeout()` signal gets emitted

Comment: Thank you very much, I just implemented you're example in my program and it seems to do exactly what I'm asking it. Many thanks. One point is still obscure to me: the abortion of the loop when the button is released (or unchecked). Does this loop->quit() aborts the loop before it reaches the end (of the timeout)? I'd prefer avoid that, and in the case the answer is yes, I'm thinking about having a bool variable that would be checked at the beginning of the loop to be true before initiating it and set to false when pressbutton released.

Comment: An event loop can basically be thought of as a `while` loop that constantly checks the event message queue for event messages. When an event is found (in this case a timeout), it passes control to whatever function has been set up to handle that message. When that function exits, control is passed back to the loop to carry on checking the queue and processing more event messages. When you tell the event loop to quit, just like any other `while` loop whose exit condition has been set, it will only exit once control returns to the loop to test the exit condition.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it definitely works as I'd like then ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I really understand what you want to do, but I will try to answer.

First, you want a Button that send a start & stop info to control a thread. You can use a checkbox to begin. This check box send a signal when its state changes. Connect this signal to a slot that perform start thread and stop according to the boolean sent.

Second, in you thread you need to launch the events loop. After, set a timer that call you repaint after every timeout.

Hope it helped.

PS: take care of execution context with you thread and Qt's objects.

Comment: Thank you, yes it's exactly what I want, to the exception that I'd prefer a pushbutton that is checkable (can stay in pressed position) than a checkbox, simply a matter of style honestly. For the rest I does look like a correct way of implementing it. I'll look into the documentation on qt threads and maybe for an example to shed some light on the way.

Comment: To use with push button, you just have to connect to the signal clicked and check and guard the state of the button and use it as the checkbox state.

Comment: Hi again, I managed to implement something along the lines you gave me, but I still have this problem of freezing the complete GUI once the loop starts (even though it is in another thread). I'm also running it on a 4 core CPU so it shouldn't be a problem, but it is... Would you know of a solution or counter for that?

Comment: I know there're some issues when using threads w/ Qt. I can advice you to check your context ID when you running threads. Maybe your timer is in the main thread when it send timeout. When I was using QThread I must create an interface that resend SIGNAL to my thread which was created in my main.